# Why is joint probability assumed to be trivially calculable in variational inference?

Tags: probability, joint-distribution, variational-bayes

The ELBO in variational inference can be written as:

$\sum q(z)\log \frac{p(x,z)}{q(x)}$.

In videos describing variational inference, I often see how lecturers decribe "joint distributions ($p(x,z)$) are given".

Examples:

https://youtu.be/xH1mBw3tb_c?t=1290

https://youtu.be/uKxtmkfeuxg?t=1616

Wouldn't calculating $p(x,z)$ entail calculating $p(x|z)p(z)$, in which we have a problem with $p(x|z)$? (How would we know the probability of $x$, even if we have a fixed $z$?)

I do understand we are using probabilistic models, and some kind of assumptions must be made. However, I was under the impression that we were only assuming the approximate prior $q(z)$.

Do we also assume a probability distribution of $p(x,z)$? If so, how would one go about doing that? Would the assumed joint distribution also be Gaussian? Would that make $p(x)$ also Gaussian? And most importantly, do we calculate a closed-form solution for $p(x,z)$ at some point in variational inference with a closed form solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variational inference isn't a model in itself, it's just a technique for tractably working with otherwise intractable latent variable models. $q(z)$ can't approximate a posterior if you have none to begin with. So, you do need to define a latent variable model first. The only "assumption" is that you have a model at all. This might be less confusing with some examples:

1. In a bayesian logistic regression model, you have a gaussian prior $p(z)$ and your observed variables are a tuple $(x,y)$ with $p((x,y)|z)$ being $\sigma(z^Txy)$ (let class $y$ be either -1 or +1).
2. In a variational autoencoder, you have standard gaussian prior $p(z)$, and $p(x|z) = \mathcal{N}(\mu = f(z),\sigma^2)$ where $f$ is some arbitrary neural network.

So, in general, $p(x,z)$ is not gaussian, and it can usually be tractably computed.